# Resize movieclip in AIR, when resizing window?

Tags: adobe, air

I need to make a resizable window. Here is my code:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
resize_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveWindow);
function moveWindow(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var corner:String;
    corner = NativeWindowResize.BOTTOM_RIGHT;
    stage.nativeWindow.startResize(corner);
}
```

It is meant to be like that, content doens't stretch. But I need outlines for this window, and they need to be resized when window is resized.

Please notice, that they are lines, so they must be resized only to one direction. So, the question is: how to create outlines for a window (I have transparent chrome).

Hope you understood,
Martti Laine